# How to trigger custom checkbox widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

And I'm using this [widget](https://github.com/hiooyUI/simple-switch) that I found online that makes checkboxes look like iOS switches. I am trying to start the switch off as on or off depending on a variable I have elsewhere. The problem is, that if I use `checkbox.click()`, then the underlying checkbox of the widget is changed but the switch is not triggered. I am trying to use this specific incident to learn more about what I don't know in JS, particularly, how the widget animation is triggered. The js for this widget is very confusing, I thought I could trigger the animation by `click()` or `onclick()` but neither works. I have no idea how to proceed.

Attached below is a minimum working example. Just download the repo in a folder called `simple_switch_master` and just add these files in the same directory!

**html file, `index.html`:**

```
<html>
<head>
    // Load in libraries
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="./simple-switch-master/jquery.simpleswitch.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./simple-switch-master/simple-switch.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div><input id=toggle  type="checkbox" class="mybox"></div>

    <script src="./control.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".mybox").simpleSwitch();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript file, `control.js`:**

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("toggle");
console.log(checkbox.checked) // Returns false as expected
checkbox.click()
console.log(checkbox.checked) // Returns true even though the switch is off
```

Comment: You can try `$(".mybox") click();`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Do you mind explaining why this works as opposed to other methods I've tried? Also, how is this different than those methods? I would also love if you add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some versions of jQuery, if you use `checkbox.checked` will return the initial state of this element (sometimes true if it started with this value), without changing. However, some versions can modify this value.

If you want to change the state, you can use `$("#elementID").prop("checked")`

You can see these details and differences between the attributes at http://api.jquery.com/prop/